# How would you solve this probability/combinatorics question?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, permutations

An urn contains eight red balls and twelve blue balls. Let B be the number of blue
balls drawn from the urn and R be the number of red balls drawn. We draw six balls
at random without replacement. State an appropriate distribution (with parameters)
for this scenario and calculate the probability we draw exactly four red balls.

My thinking behind the question:

I cannot use the Binomial distribution since the balls are not replaced and therefore the probability of picking a certain colour is not constant. In which case, I assume you need to use the combinatorics formula (without replacement, ordered) but I don't know if this is correct or how to use the formula. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hint: the order of picking does not matter, the probability to pick four red balls will be the same whether you pick four red then two blue or two blue then four red, or in some other order.

Comment: Thank you! That makes things easier. Now, I only have to work out how many ways there are of ordering 4 reds and 2 blues. Do I just do 6 nCr 4 (6 choose 4)?

Comment: Yes, use $\binom 6 4$

Comment: Much appreciated!

Comment: What matters here is which balls are selected, not the order in which they are selected.  You want to find the number of ways o selecting $R$ of the $8$ red balls and $B$ of the $12$ blue balls.  If a total of six balls are drawn, then $B = 6 - R$.

Comment: Too much incomplete and potentially confusing information, except for @Siong's nice Answer (+1). Hypergeometric: In R, combinatorial code `choose(8,4)*choose(12,2)/choose(20,6)` returns $0.119195$ as does code for hypergeometric PDF `dhyper(4,8,12,6)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw without replacement follows [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).

> In probability theory and statistics, the hypergeometric distribution is a discrete probability distribution that describes the probability of
> $k$ successes (random draws for which the object drawn has a specified feature) in
> $n$ draws, without replacement, from a finite population of size
> $N$ that contains exactly
> $K$ objects with that feature, wherein each draw is either a success or a failure.

Try to identify what are the success event, what are $N, K, n,$ and $k$ in your context and you can answer the question.